# User authentication in Elasticsearch query using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm using elastisearch using Python. My code looks somewhat like this:-

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    index="IndexPosition"
    es=Elasticsearch(['https://localhost:8080'])
    res = es.search(index='{0}'.format(index), doc_type="log",size=1000, from_=0, body={ "query": {
    "match": {
      
        ...Match condition
      }
    }
  }})
```

Now, due to changes in architecture user authentication has been added in the elasticsearch.Let's assume username-user and password-pass.How do I pass the username and password in the query..?

Answer (score 65):

You need to pass the username and password to the Elasticsearch object as shown below:

`es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:8080'], basic_auth=('user', 'pass'))`

You could also use `http_auth`, but that parameter is deprecated, and should be avoided.

Comment: How did you figure this out/find the `http_auth` parameter?

Comment: Please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77505322/7116645 for the latest version.

Answer (score 24):

You can pass username, password in url:

ex:

username: elastic

password: changeme

```
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="http://elastic:changeme@localhost:9200/")
```

using CURL

```
curl -X GET "elastic:changeme@localhost:9200/"
```

Comment: Why does *this* solution work for me, but not the one above (`http_auth=(user,pwd)`)? 

Also, saving passwords in clear text is fine for proof-of-concept, but I can't do this for the long term.

Suggestions as to how to hide the password?

Comment: @Guy A common way of avoiding hardcoding credentials in the code is using environment variables. https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ allows you to put credentials in a .env file and load them from there as environment variables

Answer (score 6):

In Elasticsearch 8.x, the `http_auth` parameter is deprecated, use `basic_auth` or `bearer_auth` respectively instead.

Elasticsearch >= 8.x basic auth example:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['https://localhost:8080'], basic_auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Elasticseach < 8.x basic auth example:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['http://localhost:8080'], http_auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Answer (score 3):

yes, use `es = Elasticsearch(hosts="http://username:password@es-endpoint:es-port/")`

Test success in es version `7.7.1`

Comment: hi, am getting an authentication error while trying to see if indices exists? Can you pls provide some sample code. Am using "res = esClient.indices.exists('metadata-store')" after creating esClient object with username/ password

Answer (score 3):

I am running ElasticSearch on Docker. ElasticSearch v8.10 automatically enables additional security (e.g., use of certificates). The certificate can be copied to the local machine by running:

`docker cp elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt .`

or, if not on Docker:

`cp /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/http_ca.crt .`

See:
[Verifying HTTPS with CA certificates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/connecting.html) & [Run Elasticsearch in Docker - Start a single-node cluster (7-8)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html)

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

# Password for the 'elastic' user generated by Elasticsearch
ELASTIC_PASSWORD = "<elastic_password>"

es = Elasticsearch(
    "https://localhost:9200",
    ca_certs="/path/to/http_ca.crt",
    basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD)
)

# Successful response!
es.info()
```

Comment: this worked for me elasticsearch in docker

Answer (score 2):

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': '8080'}], http_auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can connect the elasticsearch with below Host url config

```
es = Elasticsearch(hosts="http://user:pass@localhost:9200/")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Girish Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473026/girish-kumar)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47155087/7116645) works if you have a `elastic-search` running without `https` locally.
But if it is started with security(which is the default behaviour in ElasticSearch >=8.0) then you will have to also pass in more details about the ca certificate.
[user2514157](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2514157/user2514157) has tried to mention this is their answer but it is only for Docker container.
For a local instance of ElasticSearch, you also have an option to pass `SHA-256` fingerprint which you can copy when the ElasticSearch runs for the first time or else you can follow from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/connecting.html) to regenerate it.
Once you have the `SHA-256` fingerprint you can simply do:

```py
es_obj = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port' : 9200, 'scheme': 'https'}], ssl_assert_fingerprint=_es_ca_cert, basic_auth=(_es_username, _es_passkey), timeout=10)

print(es_obj.info()) # To verify the connection
```

Add your instance's fingerprint using `ssl_assert_fingerprint` option.

Referenced from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/connecting.html)