# How to connect to multiple elastic majors from one code

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have 3 elastic majors (8.xx, 7.xx, 5.xx) and i want to connect to each from the same code. It seems that it doesn't work with the elasticsearch library. Is there a way to do that?

the general flow is the following: I have a query, hosts and auth details. For each query I need to connect to the cluster independently from other queries and run it. How would you suggest i should do this?

Comment: [Cross cluster search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cross-cluster-search.html#ccs-supported-configurations) can help you but I'm afraid 5.x is too old to be supported by CCS.

Comment: Thanks, it solves some problems, but if anyone knows a solution to this it would really help me

Comment: Upgrade to the latest :-) All versions below 7 are EOL and unsupported

Comment: What Val said, you are gambling with your customer's data security.

Comment: That’s not my decision to make unfortunately… i have to support it…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use separate Elasticsearch client libraries that are compatible with each major version of Elasticsearch you are interacting with.
And combine that with a proxy server that abstracts the differences between the Elasticsearch versions: your code will interact with the proxy, which in turn interacts with the appropriate Elasticsearch cluster.

For instance, using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/)

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from elasticsearch5 import Elasticsearch as Elasticsearch5
from elasticsearch7 import Elasticsearch as Elasticsearch7
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

app = Flask(__name__)

# Initialize Elasticsearch clients for each version
es_clients = {
    '5.xx': Elasticsearch5([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}]),
    '7.xx': Elasticsearch7([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9201}]),
    '8.xx': Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9202}])
}

@app.route('/<version>/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def proxy(version, path):
    # Check if version is supported
    if version not in es_clients:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Unsupported version'}), 400
    
    # Split path to get index and document type (if provided)
    parts = path.split('/')
    index = parts[0]
    doc_type = parts[1] if len(parts) > 1 else None
    
    # Determine the correct Elasticsearch client to use
    es = es_clients[version]
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # Example: Handle a search request
        if path.endswith('_search'):
            body = request.get_json()
            response = es.search(index=index, doc_type=doc_type, body=body)
        else:
            response = {}  # Handle other GET requests as needed
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # Example: Handle an index request
        body = request.get_json()
        response = es.index(index=index, doc_type=doc_type, body=body)
    else:
        response = {}  # Handle other request methods as needed
    
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

The proxy server can use version-specific Elasticsearch client libraries to interact with the respective Elasticsearch clusters, and the client code can interact with the proxy server to access any of the Elasticsearch clusters.

---

> Would this work with elasticsearch api and auth?

You would need to extend the provided proxy server code to work with the Elasticsearch API and authentication, from [elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py).

### API Authentication

You will need to handle the authentication on the proxy server, which will then forward the authenticated requests to the Elasticsearch clusters.
As a first test, using Basic Authentication, you could [add the `http_auth` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73078810/6309) when creating the Elasticsearch client instances.

```py
es_clients = {
    '5.xx': Elasticsearch5([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}], basic_auth=('user', 'pass')),
    '7.xx': Elasticsearch7([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9201}], basic_auth=('user', 'pass')),
    '8.xx': Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9202}], http_auth=('user', 'pass'))
}
```

### SSL Configuration

You can also provide SSL context through the Elasticsearch client's constructor.
([Documented here for Elasticsearch7](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.17.3/#tls-ssl-and-authentication), for instance)

```py
from ssl import create_default_context

context = create_default_context(cafile="/path/to/cafile.pem")

es_clients = {
    '5.xx': Elasticsearch5([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}], ssl_context=context, http_auth=('user', 'pass')),
    '7.xx': Elasticsearch7([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9201}], ssl_context=context, http_auth=('user', 'pass')),
    '8.xx': Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9202}], ssl_context=context, http_auth=('user', 'pass'))
}
```

### API Key Authentication**:

You can [provide the `api_key` parameter](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/#api-key-authentication) when creating the Elasticsearch client instances.

```py
es_clients = {
    '5.xx': Elasticsearch5([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}], api_key=('id', 'api_key')),
    '7.xx': Elasticsearch7([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9201}], api_key=('id', 'api_key')),
    '8.xx': Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9202}], api_key=('id', 'api_key'))
}
```

### Forwarding Headers

If you have authentication headers coming from the client that need to be forwarded to Elasticsearch, make sure those headers are being forwarded in your proxy function.

```py
response = requests.request(
    method=request.method,
    url=url,
    headers={key: value for (key, value) in request.headers if key != 'Host'},
    data=request.get_data(),
    params=request.args,
    allow_redirects=False)
```

### Error Handling

Make sure your proxy server has robust error handling to manage any authentication or authorization errors that may occur, and relay meaningful error messages back to the client. Here are [examples for Elasticsearch5](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/elasticsearch5/functions/elasticsearch5.ElasticsearchException) or [more recent versions](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/96034/elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException).

```py
try:
    # Elasticsearch operation ...
except ElasticsearchException as e:
    return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 400
```

---

> I don't know the elastic major, I only know the cluster hosts and auth details (which is enough to connect to the cluster and run queries).
>
> So the general flow is the following: I have a query, hosts, and auth details. For each query, I need to connect to the cluster independently of other queries and run it. How would you suggest I should do this?"
> The main goal would be, in this case, is to connect to different Elasticsearch clusters and execute queries without the need to know the Elasticsearch version beforehand.

That means your proxy server would need to manage:

- **dynamic cluster connection**: instead of pre-defining connections to Elasticsearch clusters, you can dynamically create connections based on the provided hosts and authentication details for each query.
- **independent query execution**: execute each query independently on the specified Elasticsearch cluster, ensuring there is no cross-query interference.
- **different majors versions**: query the Elasticsearch cluster to determine its version, then adjust the query accordingly based on that version.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch5 import Elasticsearch as Elasticsearch5
from elasticsearch7 import Elasticsearch as Elasticsearch7

app = Flask(__name__)

def get_es_client(hosts, auth, version):
    if version == 5:
        return Elasticsearch5(hosts, http_auth=auth)
    elif version == 7:
        return Elasticsearch7(hosts, http_auth=auth)
    else:
        return Elasticsearch(hosts, http_auth=auth)

def get_es_version(es):
    info = es.info()
    return info['version']['number']

@app.route('/query', methods=['POST'])
def query():
    # Extract hosts and auth details from the request
    data = request.get_json()
    hosts = data.get('hosts')
    auth = data.get('auth')
    query = data.get('query')
    index = data.get('index')

    if not hosts or not query or not index:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Missing required parameters'}), 400

    # Create a new Elasticsearch client for this query
    es = get_es_client(hosts, auth, None)  # Initially None for version

    try:
        # Get the Elasticsearch version
        es_version = get_es_version(es)
        major_version = int(es_version.split('.')[0])

        # Switch to the appropriate Elasticsearch client
        es = get_es_client(hosts, auth, major_version)

        # Adjust the query based on the Elasticsearch version
        if major_version < 7:
            query = query.replace('new_field_name', 'old_field_name')

        # Execute the query
        response = es.search(index=index, body=query)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

The `get_es_client` function will create a new Elasticsearch client based on the provided hosts and authentication details. It accepts a `version` argument and return the correct version-specific Elasticsearch client based on that version.
Inside the `query` endpoint, an initial Elasticsearch client is created with `None` for the version to get the Elasticsearch version.
After determining the Elasticsearch version, the `get_es_client` function is called again with the correct version to switch to the appropriate Elasticsearch client. The query is then adjusted based on the Elasticsearch version (if necessary), and the query is executed using the version-specific Elasticsearch client.

The `query` endpoint is updated to extract the hosts, authentication details, index, and query from the request body.
A new Elasticsearch client is created for each query, and the query is executed on the specified Elasticsearch cluster.
Error handling is added to manage any exceptions that occur while executing the query.

That way, you would send a `POST` request to the `/query` endpoint with a JSON body containing the hosts, authentication details, index, and query. Each query will be executed independently on the specified Elasticsearch cluster, regardless of the Elasticsearch version.

Comment: Your answer is almost perfect. I guess my question is missing some context. I don't know the elastic major, i only know the clusters hosts and auth details (which is enough to connect to the cluster and run queries). So the general flow is the following: i have a query, hosts and auth details. *For each* query i need to connect to the cluster independently from other queries and run it. How would you suggest i should do this?

Comment: @JhonathanMizrahi OK. I have updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: But is the function given good for different majors? It seems to work with or without auth but it doesn’t address the majors issue, as they are not given, but only the hosts and auth are given, so the dictionary with versions doesn’t mean much

Comment: @JhonathanMizrahi Right, I missed that; I need to query the Elasticsearch cluster to determine its version, then adjust the query accordingly based on that version. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok so how do i determine the version?

Comment: @JhonathanMizrahi With `info = es.info()`, a simple GET to the host (or a [`curl` to host would work too](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-get-elasticsearch-version-through-the-http-api/8255/2)).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on the official client library, you can use a generic HTTP library like `requests` to send raw HTTP requests to your Elasticsearch clusters.

```
import requests

def search(base_url, index):
    response = requests.post("{es_cluster_url}/{index}/_search")
    return response.json()
```

Comment: Would this work with elasticsearch api and auth? Also, it is very inconvenient to run queries like this. Is this really the only option?